# How to merge two files based on a common column entries and preserve the header for selected columns?

Tags: awk

I have two space separated files like this:

```
head retinopathy.pheno.glm.logistic.hybrid5
CHROM POS ID REF ALT A1 A1_FREQ FIRTH. TEST OBS_CT BETA SE Z_STAT P ERRCODE DIR
1 785989 1:785989:T:C C T T 0.154229 N ADD 1608 0.166419 0.0975993 1.70512 0.0881712 . +
1 1130727 1:1130727:A:C A C C 0.0870647 N ADD 1608 0.148613 0.127899 1.16196 0.245253 . +
1 1156131 1:1156131:T:C T C C 0.161692 N ADD 1608 0.0648246 0.0991692 0.653676 0.51332 . +
1 1158631 1:1158631:A:G G A A 0.109142 N ADD 1608 -0.142729 0.111427 -1.28092 0.200221 . -
...

head gokind.retinopathy.fin
Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N
17 13775311 17:13775311:T:G 0.0494403 G T + 0.000100229 1608
11 67991077 11:67991077:G:A 0.100435 A G - 0.000100547 1608
10 92831447 10:92831447:T:C 0.0578358 C T - 0.000100775 1608
1 1158631 1:1158631:A:G 0.0578358 C A - 0.000100775 1608
...
```

I am trying to merge them by the 3rd column in both files. They have the same number of lines.
In the desired output I would like to have every entry (column) of gokind.retinopathy.fin and on the end of it I would like to add BETA,SE and A1_FREQ columns from retinopathy.pheno.glm.logistic.hybrid5 and also keep the header of every selected column. So for this particular example my desired output would be:

```
Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N BETA SE A1_FREQ
1 1158631 1:1158631:A:G 0.0578358 C A - 0.000100775 1608 -0.142729 0.111427 0.109142
```

I know how to merge both files but the problem is that my header is lost and also I am not selecting only teh above columns of interest.

This is what I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "}NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}($3 in a)&&$3=a[$3]' retinopathy.pheno.glm.logistic.hybrid5 gokind.retinopathy.fin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[(NR>1 ? $3 : "Marker")]=$11 OFS $12 OFS $7; next} $3 in a{print $0, a[$3]}' hybrid fin
Chr BP Marker MAF A1 A2 Direction pValue N BETA SE A1_FREQ
1 1158631 1:1158631:A:G 0.0578358 C A - 0.000100775 1608 -0.142729 0.111427 0.109142
```